# How to list objects that are using another object?

Tags: oracle

I have to move certain objects from a schema to another. The database is rather large and 
I want to make sure we test properly all affected objects.

On TOAD there is a Tab called "Used By" that show all objects that are referencing the selected object.

Is there a way to achieve a similar output with an SQL Command?
I tried checking the different DBA Views but I haven't been able to find any with the information I need.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143728/how-can-i-find-which-tables-reference-a-given-table-in-oracle-sql-developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the query from TOAD when you click the used_by tab - you just need to replace the `'OBJECT_NAME`' with whatever the name of the object you are interested in is, and change the `object_type` to whatever is appropriate for your object.

```
WITH Objs
     AS (    SELECT object_id
               FROM (SELECT object_id, referenced_object_id
                       FROM public_dependency
                       WHERE referenced_object_id <> object_id) pd
         CONNECT BY PRIOR object_id = referenced_object_id
         START WITH referenced_object_id = (select object_id from dba_objects where object_name = 'OBJECT_NAME' and object_type = 'TABLE'))
SELECT o.owner,
       o.object_type,
       o.object_name,
       o.object_id,
       o.status
  FROM sys.DBA_OBJECTS o, Objs
 WHERE o.Object_id = Objs.Object_id
```

You can view the SQL that TOAD generates by starting a second session, go into the session browser and then view the current statement to see the query your first TOAD session is running.